# How to access sveltekit session in endpoint?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

How do you access a session in an endpoint in sveltekit? I've tried this but no luck:

```
import { get } from 'svelte/store';    
import { getStores} from "$app/stores";

function getUser() { // <- call this at component initialization
  const { session } = getStores();
 
  return {
    current: () => get(session).user
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The session store is being populated in `src/hooks.js`, the normal flow to do so is

1. in `handle`, add some data to `event.locals`.
2. in `getSession`, use `event.locals` to create a session object.

This session object is available in the client as the session store, and on during ssr if you use the `load` functions, but it is **not** available in endpoints.

What is available though in the endpoint is the `locals` variable, that is originally passed to the `getSession` function, so you can read that one.

```js
export async function get({ locals }) {
  // code goes here
}
```

Just be aware that this means there is no synchronization between locals and the client side session, if you add something to the session it will not be available to the endpoint.  To handle this you would have to for example add new data to the cookie and parse this in the `handle` function.

Answer (score 2):

The session store only works inside svelte components, (it uses context under the hood) this provides isolation between users.

You can import the `getSession()` from `src/hooks.js` and pass the event to reuse the logic that extracts session data from the request.